# HTML5 required attribute, javascript on required found but not entered?

Tags: jquery, forms, html, validation, require

**Background info**

I am trying to upgrade a custom CMS to support the HTML5 validation like required. When I have multiple languages for the same content, the form is put into tabs like (EN,ES,DE,etc). When a user clicks each tab they edit the contents of that language. (see image)

**Problem**

When a required field in ES is not filled in and the user currently has EN selected, nothing is highlighted since the ES is currently hidden. Can I catch the html5 built in validation and use jquery to change the tab or do I need to stick with the completely jquery based validation I had before (iterating through each input with required and checking $(this).val().length)

[image: example image to show what I mean]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only solution I came up with: Displaying all languages.

```
$('#btn_submit').bind('click', function() {
    $('#content input:text[required]').parent('.lang_box').show();
});
```

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/TkrVU/3/

Comment: The problem is that they often switch constantly back and forth between each language when translating. That is why I prefer to keep it in one form so it doesn't need to be saved every time they switch language. Thanks for contributing by the way!

Comment: I understand the problem now. I provided a sample code to experiment with. Unfortunately I cannot think of a solution aside from check it manually via script or toggle all language visible on submit, yet. -- http://jsfiddle.net/TkrVU/2/

Comment: Yeah seems I am stuck with javascript then for it, thanks for trying!